# How to create a code editor for my plugin .?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, theme-development

recently i  create a plugin . That plugin have style.css file. I want to show this style .css in my plgin sub menu page . And how to make it editable and executable in admin side ,like theme editor, plugin editor etc. ?

Please help.